# Force IDE bookmark line locations?

Tags: apex, ide, developer, developer-productivity

Can we bookmark line locations in Force IDE editor as explained in the below link for eclipse?

[Eclipse IDE bookmark](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-37-3c.htm)

Looks like Force IDE editor does not allow adding bookmarks.

Just wanted to know from experts on how do you move between code blocks when you have a big source file..

Any suggestions or alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this feature is coming in Force IDE v36.0 as per [this](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/144)